# Split array vertically, add rows of data, sort, and then apply regression for rainfall data

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, regression

I have meteorological data from many sites which are compiled together in the one array e.g. the different columns below refer to `Station` `Year` `Month` `Rainfall` respectively (the rows with `nan nan nan nan` are because the `.csv` file has string headers separating each data set).

The data I'm using is about 111 sites each with 40+ years of rainfall data, this is just a subset I was experimenting with -

```
 [[             nan              nan              nan              nan]
 [  1.47130000e+04   1.96800000e+03   1.00000000e+00   2.79000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   1.96800000e+03   2.00000000e+00   1.30700000e+02]
 [  1.47130000e+04   1.96800000e+03   3.00000000e+00   8.49000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   1.96800000e+03   4.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   1.96800000e+03   5.00000000e+00   2.41000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   1.96800000e+03   6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   1.96800000e+03   7.00000000e+00   3.45000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   3.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   4.00000000e+00   5.65000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   5.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   9.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   1.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.00900000e+03   1.10000000e+01   6.20000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   1.00000000e+00   2.33300000e+02]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   2.00000000e+00   8.71000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   3.00000000e+00   4.08000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   4.00000000e+00   9.62000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   5.00000000e+00   2.21000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   7.00000000e+00   2.20000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   9.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   1.00000000e+01   8.60000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01000000e+03   1.10000000e+01   1.63000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01100000e+03   1.00000000e+00   1.10800000e+02]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01100000e+03   2.00000000e+00   6.76000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01100000e+03   3.00000000e+00   1.98000000e+02]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01100000e+03   6.00000000e+00   4.10000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01100000e+03   1.00000000e+01   2.52000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01100000e+03   1.10000000e+01   4.17000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   1.00000000e+00   2.13600000e+02]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   2.00000000e+00   7.44000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   3.00000000e+00   9.14000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   4.00000000e+00   1.70000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   5.00000000e+00   1.56000000e+01]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   7.00000000e+00   4.20000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   1.00000000e+01   3.40000000e+00]
 [  1.47130000e+04   2.01200000e+03   1.10000000e+01   7.70000000e+00]
 [             nan              nan              nan              nan]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00000000e+03   9.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00000000e+03   1.00000000e+01   8.34000000e+01]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00000000e+03   1.10000000e+01   1.17000000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00000000e+03   1.20000000e+01   4.90800000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00100000e+03   1.00000000e+00   1.64200000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00100000e+03   2.00000000e+00   6.51600000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00100000e+03   3.00000000e+00   1.36800000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.00100000e+03   4.00000000e+00   1.64400000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01000000e+03   9.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01100000e+03   1.00000000e+00   1.82400000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01100000e+03   2.00000000e+00   3.81000000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01100000e+03   3.00000000e+00   4.50800000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01100000e+03   4.00000000e+00   3.12800000e+02]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01100000e+03   5.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01100000e+03   6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.47320000e+04   2.01100000e+03   7.00000000e+00   1.60000000e+00]
 [             nan              nan              nan              nan]
 [  1.55030000e+04   1.96600000e+03   1.00000000e+00   6.47000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   1.96600000e+03   2.00000000e+00   1.14000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   1.96600000e+03   3.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   1.96600000e+03   4.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   1.96600000e+03   5.00000000e+00   2.80000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   1.96600000e+03   6.00000000e+00   3.47000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   1.96600000e+03   7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   2.00000000e+00   1.40500000e+02]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   3.00000000e+00   1.13700000e+02]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   4.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   5.00000000e+00   4.00000000e-01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   6.00000000e+00   8.60000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   7.00000000e+00   2.20000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   9.00000000e+00   4.50000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   1.00000000e+01   2.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   1.10000000e+01   2.80000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01100000e+03   1.20000000e+01   4.18000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   1.00000000e+00   4.82000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   2.00000000e+00   5.62000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   3.00000000e+00   1.45600000e+02]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   4.00000000e+00   1.62000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   5.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   6.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   9.00000000e+00   2.60000000e+00]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   1.10000000e+01   2.52000000e+01]
 [  1.55030000e+04   2.01200000e+03   1.20000000e+01   1.09900000e+02]]
```

1. I need to break up the data based on the different stations (first column). I think I can do this using `B = np.array_split(alldata,np.where(SN == 0)[0])` (where `SN` is the first column of data, with a 0 in the `Station` column by replacing initially in excel). However, this results with the `0 nan nan nan` row being included in each split array. I've also tried - `for key,items in groupby(alldata,itemgetter(0)): print(key)`, but not sure how to manipulate further the split data sets with the `groupby()` function.
2. Once the data is split into separate arrays, I need to insert rows for missing months and years and to have the corresponding cells in the new rows blank for the precipitation column. I understand how to join two lists, but I'm not sure about inserting data based on missing values from a sequence, and having it apply to the whole array. For example, with the data above, I'd like all arrays to have year and month columns extending from 1966 to 1981 so I can correlate the different months together.
3. Once all the data is of equal length I want to run a regressions between all precipitation data for the different sites. For example, say the first block of data is the "site of interest", I would like to get the r^2 value for the correlation between its rainfall data and other sites in the data set. Eventually, I would also like to alter the rainfall data to be a percentile of all the rainfall data at that site, and then correlate all the rainfall values in percentile form with the "site of interest"

I'm not sure if this makes sense, please let me know what I should add to the question (this is my first question).

**Updated Code From User's (Brionius) Comments and Suggestions:**

The code works fine up to applying the regression. Not really sure about applying a correlation using a mask.

I tried doing the correlation without a mask using `slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(rotated[0][0],rotated[i][0])` but it returned `nan` values for all the r_values, presumably because of the `nan` values in the dataset.

```
  import numpy as np

# Import data:
alldata=\
         np.genfromtxt("combinedWdata.csv",unpack=False,\
                        delimiter=",")

# Split array based on where the 'nan' values are
dataSets = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0,\
                  np.array_split(alldata,np.where(np.isnan(alldata[:,1]))[0]))

# Delete the rows with 'nan' in it.
dataSets = [np.delete(dataSet, np.where(np.isnan(dataSet)), axis=0)\
           for dataSet in dataSets]

# Assign variables to years and months
startYear = 1877
endYear = 2013
startMonth = 1
endMonth = 12
blank_rainfall_value = np.nan

# Insert rows of the form ['nan', year, month, 0] for all relevant \
    #years/months except where there is already a row containing that year/month
extendedDataSets = []
for dataSet in dataSets:
    missingMonths = [[dataSet[0][0], year, month, blank_rainfall_value] \
                     for year in range(startYear, endYear+1)\
                     for month in range(startMonth, endMonth+1) \
                     if [year, month] not in dataSet[:,1:3].tolist()]
    if len(missingMonths) > 0:
        extendedDataSets.append(np.vstack((dataSet, missingMonths)))

# Sort arrray by year, then month
finalDataSets = [np.array(sorted(dataSet, key=lambda row:row[1]+row[2]/12.0))\
                 for dataSet in extendedDataSets]

# Rotate data to compare between columns rather than rows
rotated=[]
for dataSet in finalDataSets:
    u=np.rot90(dataSet)
    rotated.append(u)
rotated=np.array(rotated)

# Delete year month and station
m=0
rotatedDel=[]
for i in rotated:
    v=[rotated[m][0]]
    rotatedDel.append(v)
rotatedDel=np.array(rotatedDel)

# Apply regression between first station and all later stations with \
#mask for nan values
m=0
r_values=[]
for i in rotatedDel:
    r_value=np.ma.corrcoef(x=\
            (np.ma.array(rotatedDel[0],mask=np.isnan(rotatedDel[0]))),y=\
            (np.ma.array(rotatedDel[m],mask=np.isnan(rotatedDel[m]))),\
             rowvar=False,allow_masked=True) 
    r_values.append(r_value)
    m=m+1
```

Comment: This is an (intended) Python array or a simple string - `[1.47130000e+04  1.96800000e+03  1.00000000e+00  2.79000000e+01]`?

Comment: Do you realize the middle dataset takes place in 1966, while you say you want the year range to be from 1968-1981?

Comment: @GLES I'm pretty sure I've intended the data to be a Python array (I imported from excel using np.genfromtxt. Just getting used to python terminology, but I believe I would want an array to do all the data manipulation I need?

Comment: @Brionius Thankyou for pointing that out; I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to your questions (1) and (2).  Can't help you with the regression without more information about what you have in mind.

```
# Split array based on where the 'nan' values are
dataSets = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, np.array_split(alldata,np.where(np.isnan(alldata[:,1]))[0]))

# Delete the rows with 'nan' in it.
dataSets = [np.delete(dataSet, np.where(np.isnan(dataSet)), axis=0) for dataSet in dataSets]

startYear = 1966
endYear = 1981
startMonth = 1
endMonth = 12
blank_rainfall_value = np.nan

# Insert rows of the form ['nan', year, month, 0] for all relevant years/months except where there is already a row containing that year/month
extendedDataSets = []
for dataSet in dataSets:
    missingMonths = [[dataSet[0][0], year, month, blank_rainfall_value] for year in range(startYear, endYear+1) for month in range(startMonth, endMonth+1) if [year, month] not in dataSet[:,1:3].tolist()]
    if len(missingMonths) > 0:
        extendedDataSets.append(np.vstack((dataSet, missingMonths)))

# Sort arrray by year, then month
finalDataSets = [np.array(sorted(dataSet, key=lambda row:row[1]+row[2]/12.0)) for dataSet in extendedDataSets]

for dataSet in finalDataSets:
    print dataSet
    print
```

Comment: Thankyou Brionius for this. It works for the data set I put in the question. However when I apply to my complete data set (i.e. 111 sites of rainfall data, covering years from 1896 to 2012) it doesn't work and gives the error "ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly".

Comment: I've played around with adding and removing data to the original data set and the error appears to only come up when the very first site (i.e. the first block of data before the first [nan,nan,nan,nan] row) contains a row with a 12 in the month column. If I import the data with a [nan,nan,nan,nan] row above the first data block (without any month 12 in the dataset) I get the following error: "IndexError: too many indices"

Comment: @Oregano: Ok, I updated the solution above (added a filter to the first statement to remove zero-length data sets), to fix the `IndexError` problem, however I can't reproduce the `ValueError` problem - I tried adding a row at the top with a month of 12.  Could you post some data that causes the error for you?

Comment: I've added data to the question which gives me the `ValueError` problem

Comment: I find the new data subset gets an error with the data as is. But runs fine if I remove the rows with data containing month 12 for the first and last sites (it seems to be OK with the month 12 value in the middle data set)

Comment: If you check the output data, it hasn't added all months for the years (e.g. months in second data set for 1968 only go from 1 to 3, then 11 to 12). We I run the new data set in the question with the rows containing months 12 removed; the output only has inserted month 12 for all the years preceding the start of data collection at that site.

Comment: Ok, I found a silly mistake - it's in the really long line (see the code above, I fixed it and marked the line with a comment).  The above code no longer throws a `ValueError`, but I'm in a bit of a hurry, so I can't check to see if the output is actually correct - I'll look at it later, or you can check.

Comment: I've tried the new code with the complete data set.  It doesn't work for `not in dataSet[:,2:4]` but does work for `not in dataSet[:,1:4]` or `[not in dataSet[:,0:i]`. However when it works I get duplicate rows for months which already had a 'rainfall' value: one is the original row, the second is the equivalent row with 'nan' replacing the rainfall value.
I thought to try to delete the duplicates with something like `finalDatas=[]
for dataSet in dataSets:
    finalData=[]
    date=(dataSet[1],dataSet[2])
    if date not in finalData:` But not really sure what to do.

Comment: I'm not meant to say thanks, but really thanks! You have no idea how much I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Oregano:  Ok, that silly mistake I fixed was not a mistake at all, I was just in a rush.  The problem was twofold - it wasn't correctly checking whether months were missing.  I fixed that.  It also wasn't handling the case where there were no months to add.  I fixed that too.  I'm pretty sure it'll work now :)

Comment: Thanks for that it works well! :)I've tried to apply the regression (see original question) but I get funny results from the `np.ma.corrcoef` step. Maybe I should make a new question for that? And should all these comments be moved to chat (I get a suggestion popping up to do that)?

Comment: @Oregano - Yep, that's a topic for a new question, and yeah, we probably should have moved this to chat, but it's ok.